# Problem with em-dash symbol using extsizes package

Tags: typography, viewers, cyrillic, extsizes

I use package `extsizes` for 14 pt text size in my document.
But there are a problem with em-dash symbol in PDF: in some scales (e.g. 74%, 100%, 204%. but not 125% and 150%) dash symbol is invisible:

100% scale -- dash symbol is invisible:
[image: 100% scale -- dash symbol is invisible :(]

125% zoom:
[image: 125% scale -- ok]

It is problem of `extsizes` package, pdflatex or something else? How can I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\begin{document}
Архимед научил нас, что много раз понемногу~"--- это много (говоря языком пословицы, капля камень долбит).
Я убежден, что когда выполняется какая-нибудь большая работа, в частности, пишется книга, верно и обращение этого архимедова принципа: единственный способ написать большую книгу~"--- писать понемножку, но с неослабевающим упорством каждый день без исключения, без отпуска.
Хороший способ сохранять производительность труда~"--- заканчивать каждый день, заправившись горючим на завтра.
С чего вы начнете завтра?
Что будет в следующем параграфе?
Как его назвать?
(Я рекомендовал бы подыскивать возможно короткие названия для каждого раздела до или после того как он написан; даже если вы не собираетесь печатать названия разделов.
Цель такого занятия — в проверке того, насколько хорошо спланирован параграф: если вы не можете его озаглавить, возможно, он не имеет единого, цельного сюжета.)
Иногда первую завтрашнюю фразу я записываю сегодня; некоторые авторы начинают сегодняшнюю работу проверкой и переписыванием вчерашней последней страницы.
Во всяком случае, заканчивайте каждую порцию работы на подъеме, а между порциями давайте своему подсознанию какую-нибудь солидную пищу.
Поразительно, как эффективно удается перехитрить себя таким способом; техника подготовки достаточна для преодоления естественного человеческого отвращения к творческой работе.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a viewer issue.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm not so sure. Have you not seen this problem yourself? I actually usually see it with printing but it can appear in the viewer, too. All em-dashes and/or all en-dashes disappear. I don't know if it is the same issue - if it is, it is not related to `extsizes` as I've never used it.

Comment: No need to load `babel` twice, by the way. If once isn't enough, twice won't help!

Comment: @cfr I processed the document and using Okular zoomed it in and out (from 30% up to 1.200% including the allegedly problematic 100% and 204%) and the em-dashed were there. I can't print the document, unfortunately, right now, however.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well, you didn't say you'd *tested* it before ;). All I meant was that I have seen a similar issue and that looks might, therefore, be deceptive. However, sometimes looks aren't deceptive even when they might have been. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: From what I can see, the em-dash is as thick as the corresponding one in `ecrm1440`, just shorter. On my machine, the `sfrm1440.pfb` font from CM-Super is loaded in the PDF file, as it covers both EC and LA fonts. Maybe you can try an experiment: with `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}`, change one of the `---` into  `{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont---}---` and look at the result. Do the two dashes appear and disappear simultaneously?

Comment: @egreg, I just tried your suggestion. The result is the same, the problem is still present.

Comment: You mean that invisibility applies to both dashes, depending on the magnification, or just to the Cyrillic one?

Comment: @egreg, yes, invisibility applies to both dashes

Comment: @Stas So it's a viewer problem. What is it? On what OS?

Comment: @egreg, it's Adobe Reader XI (last update, version 11.0.11) on Windows 7. However, when I compile my document without `extsizes` (also with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`), I don't have any troubles with dashes.

Comment: @Stas PDF viewers snap to a pixel grid, so it can happen, at small magnifications, that the dash sits just in the middle of the grid and neither the top nor the bottom parts are drawn. Try another PDF viewer to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seams to be a viewer issue.